# Evince won't open; authorization error

Tags: pdf, evince

I'm trying to use evince to open a pdf as a regular user. It doesn't open. I try from the command line and get:

> Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
>
> Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:

Can anyone offer some advice?
Thanks.

Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: That's the kind of error you'd usually get when trying to open a GUI program from a non-GUI environment (such as a server or WSL installation)

Comment: 1.) You don't have access rights to the file, but, because reason 2, `evince` didn't find a way to ask you for a password; 2.) You are trying to run `evince a document viewer application for the GNOME desktop environment` in a non-GUI, non-Gnome environment.

Comment: @waltinator the "authorization" in this context is authorization to connect to the display server (e.g. `xauth`) - nothing to do with file access afaik

Comment: Okay. But this used to work in the wm I’m currently using (openbox). I’m sure it did. Other viewers work fine, so nothing serious.

Comment: Is your evince installed via  apt - or is it a snap? Are you trying to open it from a terminal emulator inside the wm, or from another tty?

Comment: Installed via apt. I tried first from my graphical file manager. But it wouldn’t open. So I used the CLI to get the error message posted above. Just from my wm.

Comment: I get this error message if I run `evince` from a terminal session running as root (using `sudo`) but if I run it as the same user as GNOME is logged in as, I get no issues. Could this also be the cause in your case?

Comment: Just running as a regular user.